# Visual Studio 2008 debug output in english?

Tags: visual-studio, internationalization

I've got Visual Studio 2008 Professional german version. In the settings -> Environment -> international... is only German available.

That's fine - there's just one thing that bothers me. All the debug output is in german too, which makes it much more difficult to search the web for solutions.

Is there any way to change the language of the debug output to english without installing another version of Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question pretty much sums up why I, as a developer, has always used (and probably always will use) English-language versions of all development related software.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is handled by the .NET framework. If you change the default language on your machine via control panel, the debug output should change accordingly.

Comment: hey and thanks! If possible, I'd like to find a way without changing the language of my OS

Comment: You can't on non-MUI versions of Windows.